# Unable to connect to postgresql using Go and pq

Tags: postgresql, go, pq

I'm trying to connect a Go application with postgresql.

The app import postgresql driver:

```
"crypto/tls"
"database/sql"
"fmt"
"log"
"os"
"os/signal"
 ...
_ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
_ "github.com/lib/pq"
_ "github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3"
```

and uses like it to connect to the database:

```
driver, cnxn := dbFromURI(dbURI)
db, err := sql.Open(driver, cnxn)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

and the dbFromUri method just split the info

```
func dbFromURI(uri string) (string, string) {
    parts := strings.Split(uri, "://")
    return parts[0], parts[1]
}
```

My URI works locally when i run the command : `psql postgresql://user:user@172.20.0.1:5432/lcp`

But in go i Go, I got

```
./lcpserver
2021/03/07 02:00:42 Reading config /root/lcp-server-install/lcp-home/config/config.yaml
panic: pq: SSL is not enabled on the server
```

I tried this URI for Go without success : `psql postgresql://user:user@172.20.0.1:5432/lcp?sslmode=disable`

Do you have any idea why i can't connect ?
I tried with my aws rds postgres database, and got same result. Thnaks for the help.

complete code of the server
https://github.com/readium/readium-lcp-server/blob/master/lcpserver/lcpserver.go

I change the typo and the demo provided i succeed the connexion. But in the lcp server i style got the same issue.

```
postgres://user:user@172.20.0.1:5432/lcp?sslmode=disable
```

EDIT 2:

The error is due to the fact that the script tries prepare command. I update the minimal example and it fails too.

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    "strings"

    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
)

func dbFromURI(uri string) (string, string) {
    parts := strings.Split(uri, "://")
    return parts[0], parts[1]
}

func main() {
    driver, cnxn := dbFromURI("postgres://user:user@172.20.0.1:5432/lcp?sslmode=disable")

    fmt.Println("The driver " + driver)
    fmt.Println("The cnxn " + cnxn)

    db, err := sql.Open(driver, cnxn)

     _, err = db.Prepare("SELECT id,encryption_key,location,length,sha256,type FROM content WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1")
    if err != nil {
         fmt.Println("Prepare failed")
         fmt.Println(err)

    }

   if err == nil {
        fmt.Println("Successfully connected")
    } else {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

I got :
prepare failed

```
pq: SSL is not enabled on the server
2021/03/07 17:20:13 This panic 3
panic: pq: SSL is not enabled on the server
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first problem is a typo in the connection string: `postgresql://user:user@172.20.0.1:5432/lcp?sslmode=disable`. In Go code it should be `postgres://user:user@172.20.0.1:5432/lcp?sslmode=disable`.

We also need to pass the full connection string as the second argument to `sql.Open`. For now, the `dbFromURI` function returns `user:user@172.20.0.1:5432/lcp?sslmode=disable`, but we need `postgres://user:user@172.20.0.1:5432/lcp?sslmode=disable`, because [pq is waiting for this prefix](https://github.com/lib/pq/tree/072e83d238c297c71cab11154695af301010031e/connector.go#L60) to [parse it](https://github.com/lib/pq/tree/072e83d238c297c71cab11154695af301010031e/url.go#L32).

After fixing this, I was able to establish a connection using a minimal postgres client based on your code.

To try this yourself, start the server with the following command:

```sh
docker run --rm -p 5432:5432 -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=some_password postgres
```

And try to connect using the following client code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"

    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
)

func main() {
    cnxn := "postgres://postgres:some_password@127.0.0.1:5432/lcp?sslmode=disable"

    _, err := sql.Open("postgres", cnxn)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    _, err = db.Prepare("SELECT id,encryption_key,location,length,sha256,type FROM content WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1")
    if err != nil {
         fmt.Println("Prepare failed")
         panic(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your anwser. I correct the typo. And when running your little test function, i get   `Successfully connected` but when i run the server i still got the same error. I added print and i  have `2021/03/07 16:02:05 The driver postgres
2021/03/07 16:02:05 The cnxn user:user@172.20.0.1:5432/lcp?sslmode=disable
panic: pq: SSL is not enabled on the server`

Comment: I finally found the cause of the error. I updated your minimal example and it fails too.

Comment: @TeddyKossoko so what was the problem? Did the 'Prepare' function get an invalid argument?

Comment: i don't know. The issue is not corrected yet. I don't understand why i have the issue. The db.prepare works fine for sqlite3 and even mysql because it is generic. Do you have any idea ?

Comment: i added db.Ping() to check db with your example, but it fails too. 
    `db, err := sql.Open(driver, cnxn)

    err = db.Ping()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("it fails to ping")
        fmt.Println(err)
    }` What is strange, sql.Open returns `err == nil`

Comment: Yes, it seems I managed to fix it. Try to replace the second parameter of `sql.Open` with the complete connection string: `postgres://postgres:some_password@127.0.0.1:5432/lcp?sslmode=disable` (including `postgres://`!). I need some time to read `pq` sources more to correct my answer.

Comment: @TeddyKossoko Is readium-lcp-server your project? I think we can contribute this fix to the upstream.

Comment: it is not my project. It is managed by a Europen Organization. And yes, their are open for contribution because they never tested postgresql. They are looking for it. Because you found the solution, i let you push the contribution. I will notify them tomorrow for your work ;)

Comment: @TeddyKossoko Thanks, I'll create them a PR today.

Comment: wait a minute. Just previous correction is not enough. File index.go in index folder must be updated `get, err := db.Prepare("SELECT id,encryption_key,location,length,sha256,type FROM content WHERE id = $1 LIMIT 1")` `?` must be replaced by `$1` and i still go some pg errors when i run the server and start pushing data in it

Comment: @TeddyKossoko Yes, I see. The `Prepare` syntax is different in the sqlite3 and postgres drivers. And we also can't remove `dbFromURI`, because sqlite3 driver expects the string without the `sqlite3://` prefix.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229629/discussion-between-teddy-kossoko-and-jubnzv).